# Google Tables (Area120) How to update Checklist field type?

Tags: google-apps-script

This is for an Area 120 Tables

There are simple checkbox fields and Checklist field types.

I cannot find in the Documentation how to update the children items in the checklist from Apps Script.

Here is the code to update a checkbox:

```
{row: {name: r.name, values: {["Confirmation Received"]: Boolean(true)}}}
  ));
  Area120Tables.Tables.Rows.batchUpdate({requests: updateRequest}, tableName);
```

Looking for the syntax on how to update the children in a Checklist.

The Checklist object has Name, and Options, but I do not know how to set the Child options in the checklist to true.
I cannot find any documentation on the Field type.

https://support.google.com/area120-tables/answer/10011387?hl=en&ref_topic=10081846

Comment: Please provide the full code and a clear explanation about the current and expected results. See **[ask]**

Comment: That is the problem-  I showed how to update a Checkbox.' In the Google Documentation they do not explain how to update the values of a Checklist.

The Checklist object has Name, and Options, but I do not know how to Check off the Child options in the checklist. I cannot find any documentation on the Object

Comment: A check box is actually a dataValidation

Comment: Default checkboxes have the cell values of "TRUE" and "FALSE".  Yes they are strings

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't intuitive to me, but you send the value of the field to the name of the step you want to check.  So the below code checked the Step1 box in the checklist.

```
{
  row: {
    values: {
      "TestChecklist": "Step1"
    }
  }
},
```

Not sure how you would uncheck it though?  Any ideas?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).